# Проверка лайка на ютубе

Tags: python, selenium, youtube, проверка

Как проверить, стоит ли лайк на видео, при помощи Selenium и Python?Поставить лайк я смог,но перед этим нужно проверить стоит ли он вообще,а как это сделать - не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотри артибут класса в коде елемента лайк. После лайка атрибут класса меняется на `default-active`. Как проверить атрибут класса описан здесь (Java): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713009/how-to-check-if-element-contains-specific-class-attribute

Comment: Я сделал похожее на питоне:

`element = find_element_by_xpath("find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id='top-level-buttons']/ytd-toggle-button-renderer[1]/a')")//Просто кнопка лайка
if(element.getAttribute("class").contains("default-active")):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='top-level-buttons']/ytd-toggle-button-renderer[1]/a").click()`
https://ibb.co/1K4Y94G
Но мне selenium ругается, что "name 'find_element_by_xpath' is not defined"
Какой тут name вообще нужен?

Comment: @Stepashka20 имеется ввиду смена например с `class="style-scope ytd-menu-renderer force-icon-button style-text"` на `class="style-scope ytd-menu-renderer force-icon-button style-default-active"` при нажатии. Нажми правой кнопкой на лайк и открой код элемента; раскрой все что касается этой кнопки; нажимай несколько раз на лайк и следи какие классы меняются в HTML

Comment: find_element_by_xpath у тебя лишний похоже

Comment: я так и не понял,что нужно в element записывать?Название класса не подходит,find_element_by_class_name тоже

Comment: Всё,ошибку нашёл)Спасибо